# Filtering Get-ADGroups with question mark wildcard doesn't seem to work

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a list of AD groups that have a name that starts with "Users-####-" (# is a number 0-9).

I've tried using `Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "Users-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-*"}` and `Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "Users-????-*"}`, but got no results.

I can of course use `Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "Users-*"}`, but this will also include all the groups that have something else than four characters after Users-.

I then decided to try using Where-Object and the this code returned the expected groups

`Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Users-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-*"}`

According to Microsoft documentation about [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.2), both ways I tried **should** work, but they actually don't.

Anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong or is this just a bug in how ADGroup filtering works?

Comment: The only supported wildcard for ActiveDirectory Filter is `*`. so this is expected, not a bug.

Comment: The `Get-AD* -Filter` parameter is constrained by the fact that the query filter has to be translated to LDAP - and LDAP doesn't recognize `?` as a wildcard

Comment: Thanks for all quick and very thorough answers. Learned (or possible re-learned) a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> According to Microsoft documentation about wildcards, both ways I tried **should work**, but they actually don't.

That's a reasonable assumption, but the `-Filter` parameter exposed by some cmdlets in the `ActiveDirectory` module is a *deceptive construct* - it's designed to *look like* PowerShell's native operator syntax, but "underneath the hood" the cmdlet translates the filter expression to a valid LDAP query filter:

```
name -like "Users-*"
# is translated to
(name=Users-*)

$_.Name -like "Users-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-*"
# is translated to
(Name=Users-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-*)
```

Since LDAP doesn't recognize the wildcard range construct `[0-9]`, it ends up querying the directory store for objects where the name *literally* starts with  `Users-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-` - same goes for `?`.

Since `*` is the only wildcard accepted by LDAP, the closest you can get is:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "Users-*-*"}
```

And then filter the results further on the client with `Where-Object` (in which case we're back to PowerShell performing the comparison and we can use all the wildcards again):

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "Users-*-*"} | Where-Object Name -like 'Users-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-*'
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [about_ActiveDirectory_Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)):

> Note: PowerShell wildcards, other than "*", such as "?" are not
> supported by the `-Filter` parameter syntax.

In this case, you can combine `-LDAPFilter` with `Where-Object` to keep your query compatible and efficient:

```
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(name=Users-*-*)" | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -like "Users-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-*"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-Filter` in this case as pre-filter, so at least you will get only groups with names starting with `Users-`.
Then in a further Where-Object clause you can specify further and in this case I would use regex `-match` there like:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'Users-*'" | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^Users-\d{4}-.*' }
```

P.S. `-Filter` should be a **string**, not a scriptblock

Answer (score 0):

The filters in the Powershell Active Directory module have [odd behaviors.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28485.powershell-filter-results-with-active-directory-module-cmdlets.aspx)

### Filter or Where Clause

> There are two ways to restrict the output of an AD cmdlet like
> Get-ADUser. First, you can use the -LDAPFilter or -Filter parameters
> to filter the output. Second, you can pipe the results to the
> Where-Object cmdlet. Where possible, the first method is more
> efficient for two reasons.
>
> Filtering is done on the domain controller instead of the local
> client. The domain controller is more likely to be a server class
> computer optimized for queries. Filtering results in a smaller
> resultset sent over the network from the domain controller to the
> client. In contrast, the Where-Object cmdlet only filters on the local
> client after the resultset has been sent from the remote computer. For
> example, you could retrieve all users with a department that starts
> with "IT" using the Where-Object cmdlet as follows:
>
> `Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties department | Where-Object {$_.department -Like "it*"} | Select sAMAccountName, department` The
> resultset from the Get-ADUser statement includes all users in the
> domain. A more efficient method to get the same results would use a
> filter, similar to below:
>
> `Get-ADUser -Filter {department -Like "it*"} -Properties department | Select sAMAccountName, department` Now only the users needed are
> included in the resultset from Get-ADUser. In a test domain with 2,150
> users (7 of which have "IT" departments) the first command above took
> 4 times as long as the second (average of 10 trials each with 16
> minutes between trials). The difference could be substantial in a
> domain with ten's of thousands of users.
>
> Also, note that the statements above use the -Properties parameter to
> specify only the properties needed. The default properties exposed by
> the cmdlet are always included, like sAMAccountName in this case. If
> you request all properties, with -Properties *, the resultset will
> include many properties for each user. The resultset will be much
> smaller if you only specify the extended properties needed, like
> department in this case. Repeating the last command above in the test
> domain with 2,150 users, but requesting all properties (with
> -Properties *) required 75% more time on average to complete. The default and extended properties exposed by the Get-ADUser cmdlet are
> documented in Active Directory: Get-ADUser Default and Extended
> Properties.

### PowerShell Filter Syntax

> The PowerShell Active Directory module cmdlets support an extended
> form of the PowerShell Expression Language. PowerShell documentation
> indicates that PowerShell syntax filters should be enclosed in braces.
> But there are many examples where single quotes or double quotes are
> used instead. As you might expect, this affects how the filter is
> interpreted.
>
> Using String Attributes The following table shows some example
> PowerShell syntax filters using string properties, like Department.
> Some filters result in error, others do not raise an error but never
> produce results. The variable $Dept is defined as previously.

```
Filter  Result
-Filter {department -eq "IT Department"}    Works
-Filter {department -eq $Dept}  Works
-Filter {department -eq "$Dept"}    No Results
-Filter {department -eq '$Dept'}    No Results
-Filter "department -eq $Dept"  Error
-Filter 'department -eq $Dept'  Works
-Filter {department -eq "it*"}  No Results
-Filter {department -Like "it*"}    Works
-Filter "department -Like ""it*"""  Works
-Filter "department -Like 'it*'"    Works
-Filter 'department -Like "it*"'    Works
-Filter 'department -Like ''it*'''  Works
-Filter {department -ge "IT"}   Works
Some of these results may not be expected.
```

> For example, you might expect enclosing a variable in a quoted string
> to work. The best policy might be to always enclose PowerShell syntax
> filters in braces, and to refrain from quoting variables.
>
> The last example using the "-ge" operator is only useful in rare
> situations. The filter will result in any departments that are
> lexicographically greater than or equal to "IT". For example, it will
> return "Test Department", because "T" is greater than "I".